# How to communicate with Bitcoin core 0.17 using bitcoinj for hd wallet creation?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, wallet, bip32-hd-wallets, bitcoinj

Hi am building one hobby project and i want to perform some operations in my own bitcoin core 0.17 by using bitcoinj lib. so is there any way by which we can use bitcoin-core 0.17,bitcoinj for hd wallet creation with derivation path.

Comment: If you're more specific about the functionality you need it would be easier to help you. Do you want to use Bitcoinj to generate a HD wallet, or Bitcoin Core? If you're using Bitcoin Core, Bitcoinj is probably not the best solution for communicating with Core.

Comment: Actually,i want to use bitcoin-core for HD wallet creation by using derivation path and also want to maintain each account seperately. For that as per my knowledge we can maintain the different derivation path by changing account level. so i want to know how we can implement derivation path in bitcoin-core unlike bitcoinj ?

Comment: Bitcoin Core generally does not expose much control over which HD paths are used. However, it has a label system, where you can call `getnewaddress my-label`. Does that cover your use case? If you want fine grained control over HD derivation path you will probably need to use another wallet, or make your own.

Comment: You also don’t want to be using an ancient version of bitcoin core. 0.17 is very old.

Comment: As far as I know, BitcoinJ does not implement a Bitcoin Core RPC client, so there isn't a way to call Core instead (regardless of whether the functionality you want exists in Core).

Comment: Thanks @torkel . If we use label to get new addresses then how we can re-import the same addresses into another bitcoin core and how to make transaction on both the servers. Could you please suggest any wallet which support full node with hd support & allow to create custom derivation path. please hint me on how i can do changes in bitcoin core based on custom derivation.

Comment: Is custom derivation path a hard requirement? I'm having a hard time imagining a use case where what derivation path is used would affect your application. If you're willing to drop that requirement, you can use [Electrum](https://electrum.org/) to have two servers sharing the same seed (and thereby wallet).

Comment: Hi, I am able to connect my local node(bitcoin-core 0.17) with bitcoinj. Also able to create address using bitcoinj library through derivation path, but that address does not belongs to my local node server as when i am trying to get information of that address by cli command "getaddressinfo". it returns "ismine" as false in response. If i connect my local node through bitcoinj and create address that address should belongs to my local node server so how we can achieve this? One more thing, Is there any way to use bitcoin-core's wallet.dat file through bitcoinj library?